# How to test Android app on Microsoft Azure

Tags: android, azure, github

I have an android project on Github and I have successfully linked it with Azure pipelines,Problem is in running the project so i see the layout being launched, Its paid work and am gonna aprreciate any help to achieve this so far

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Microsoft App Center as part of your Azure pipeline and use it to manage your distribution and testing.
See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute?view=azure-devops